# Long wait time for Schengen visa at NYC Swiss visa desk

Tags: visas, schengen

I am Indian citizen residing in NYC, US. I intend to travel to Switzerland on a Schengen visa in June end. However the the online booking system for appointment for visa interview is showing no slots available till July first week at the NYC visa desk. What should I do?

Comment: You can modify your travel plans to include another Schengen country for a few days then apply for the visa from that embassy. You have to be creative.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution is to change your plans and instead plan a longer stay in a different Schengen country. That way you would be able to book an interview slot at a different consulate.

**Example:** assuming you planned for a 5-day stay in Switzerland you can amend your plans to spend 6 days in France and 5 days in Switzerland. You would then apply at the French consulate and receive an 11-day visa which you would use to follow your submitted itinerary.